# Disable HTML5 on YouTube without account?

Tags: youtube

YouTube seems to be defaulting to HTML5 for me (using Chrome), such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jKOt0qfaqA). I'm unable to login to YouTube ("You are not eligible to create an account." on “Sign In”), so how can I turn off HTML5 as a guest?

I tried `&html5=false` in the address bar and it didn't help. The reason I need this is because YouTube is not really buffering the video for me in HTML5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki) user script and go to Youtube. You get a settings button now in the upper right corner. Click it to open the settings, switch to **Player** and select your preferred player.

[image]

Disable **Dash Playback** if buffering still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [**Flash Player for YouTube** extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash%C2%AE-player-for-youtube/lajdkhdcndkniopfefocbgbkofflagpm?hl=en) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/).

> A very lightweight extension that allows you to watch YouTube videos using Flash Player instead of the default HTML5 player.
>
> The Flash Player will consume less material resources (CPU, RAM) if your PC or laptop doesn't easily support HTML5 videos.
>
> Why you should try it? Because for a lot of people the HTML5 player is laggy and causes playback issues.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps as images are given below:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/samoR.jpg)

Comment: The images are too small to be embedded and it looks that one of the images is repeated.

Comment: plzz download the image then you will see it clearly.or you can save as image to view it .