# How to disable YouTube HTML5 player? ( & Auto Play)

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

Every day I go through my YT subscriptions list and open every new video in a new tab (CMD + click). Then I play the 1st new video, close the tab, switch to the next tab..

Several weeks ago all videos were using the HTML5 player (not the Flash player).

The HTML5 player sucks!
1.) It auto-plays the video. This sucks when opening 10 - 30 videos at once!
2.) It's slow
3.) I don't want it

http://www.youtube.com/html5 says HTML5 beta is not enabled.

How to get rid of it?

I already installed The YouTube Center Greasemonkey Script, this gives me back the Flash player, but auto play still isn't disabled correctly:

When opening these 10-30 videos from my subscription list, some of them auto play for several seconds before they stop.

WHAT TO DO ?? :(

Using Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

E.g. this video plays for 0-5 seconds before it switches to the Flash player (then it stops playing): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGA57mMI0J8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable HTML5 on YouTube without account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/disable-html5-on-youtube-without-account)

Comment: Actually it's not. My problem is the HTML5 player AND auto play. Also there's no solution to this question.

Comment: You can control both with the settings explained in the answer. I know it, because I’m doing exactly that. :)

Comment: I've already enabled "Disable auto play" but it doesn't work as expected. Try it with the YouTube video mentioned above. 1.) I load the page 2.) Video starts in the HTML5 player, with audio! :( 3.) After a few seconds it shows the Flash player -> Video and audio stops

Comment: Works for me. _Prevent Auto-Play:_ checked, _Player Type:_ Flash. No switch, no auto-play. Browser Opera 12.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 30, maybe that's the problem?!

Comment: Maybe. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/issues/110) for Chrome. You should add your setup and the steps to reproduce it. That would help the developer. In the mean time, you could use another browser for Youtube.

Comment: Here's how I enforced my dominion over Chrome: Find the file called ffmpegsumo.dll where Chrome is installed (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\30.xxxxx\ for me). Delete it or move it out of that folder. I also moved nacl_irt_*.nexe.

Comment: There seems to be an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-youtube-html5-pla/enmofgaijnbjpblfljopnpdogpldapoc?hl=en) for that

Answer (score 1):

Install the [YouTube Flash Player (Chrome version)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash%C2%AE-player-for-youtube/lajdkhdcndkniopfefocbgbkofflagpm?hl=en) / [(Firefox version)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/) extension:

> This add-on forces YouTube to play videos using Flash Player instead of the HTML5 player.

<sup>Source: [My answer in a similar Super User question](https://superuser.com/a/897145/10259)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\google\chrome\application\32.0.1700.76`
2. Delete `ffmpegsumo.dll`

Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Go to `/opt/google/chrome`
2. Delete Ïlibffmpegsumo.so`

You will never play HTML5 again. A new install will give you again the possibility to play HTML5.